# Grothendieck's Galois theory implies Galois theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Szamuely's book *Galois groups and fundamental groups* formulates several variants of the main theorem of Galois theory. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHHk8.png) is the usual formulation (dual isomorphism of posets between intermediate fields and subgroups). [Then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX3wp.png) there is also Grothendieck's version (dual equivalence of categories between finite étale algebras and actions of the Galois group).

*Question:* Does Grothendieck's version imply the usual formulation of the main theorem of Galois theory? If yes, why?

This question seems to be a very natural one - but as far as I can see it is not discussed in the book (am I missing something?). There are also two versions of the classification of covering spaces: firstly, as a bijection between subgroups and covers; secondly, as an equivalence of categories between covers of $X$ and $\pi_1(X,x)$-sets. Same question: does the equivalence of categories imply the bijection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it comes down the treatment of non-connected covers / non-transitive actions.
Classical Galois theory – whether applied to field extensions or to covering spaces – focuses on connected covers and transitive group actions.
Every transitive left action of a (discrete) group $G$ is isomorphic to the set of left cosets of some subgroup of $G$ (with the obvious left $G$-action), which is how subgroups enter the picture.

One way to make this precise is to define connectedness abstractly.

**Definition.**
A **connected object** in a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finitary (resp. infinitary) coproducts is an object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{C} (X, -) : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$ preserves finitary (resp. infinitary) coproducts.

*Remark.*
According to this definition, an initial object is never connected.

**Example.**
A $G$-set is connected in the sense above if and only if it is transitive.

**Example.**
A ring $A$ is connected in $\textbf{CRing}^\textrm{op}$ considered as a category with finitary (!!!) products if and only if $\operatorname{Spec} A$  is a connected topological space.
(In this context, $\emptyset$ is not connected.)
Equivalently, $A$ is connected in $\textbf{CRing}^\textrm{op}$ if and only if $A$ has exactly two idempotent elements, namely $0$ and $1$.

**Example.**
A finite étale algebra over a field $k$ is connected in $\textbf{FÉt}_k{}^\textrm{op}$ if and only if it is a finite separable field extension of $k$.

So we can extract the objects studied in classical Galois theory, at least.
To get the actual posets is a bit more difficult.
This should not be surprising: after all, in the context of field extensions, this amounts to choosing an algebraic closure and embedding all the field extensions into that algebraic closure.
But it can be done: this is what the fibre functor is for.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $U : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$ be a functor.
We may form the following category $\textbf{El} (U)$:

- An object is a pair $(X, x)$ where $X$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$ and $x \in U (X)$.
- A morphism $(X, x) \to (Y, y)$ is a morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $U (f) (x) = y$.
- Composition and identities are inherited from $\mathcal{C}$.

Incidentally, $U : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$ is representable if and only if $\textbf{El} (U)$ has an initial object.

In the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of connected $G$-sets and $U$ is the forgetful functor, $\textbf{El} (U)$ is a preorder category, which can be canonically identified with the poset of open subgroups of $G$: just send $(X, x)$ to the stabiliser subgroup of $x$.

In the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the opposite of the category of finite separable field extensions of $k$ and $U$ is the functor sending $K$ to the set of $k$-embeddings $\iota : K \to \bar{k}$, where $\bar{k}$ is a chosen algebraic closure of $k$, $\textbf{El} (U)$ is a preorder category, which can be canonically identified with the opposite of the poset of finite subextensions of $\bar{k}$: just send $(K, \iota)$ to the image of $\iota : K \to \bar{k}$.

Since Grothendieck's formulation asserts that the opposite of the category of finite étale $k$-algebras is equivalent to the category of finite $\textrm{Gal} (k)$-sets *as categories equipped with fibre functors*, restricting to the subcategory of connected objects and applying the construction above recovers the classical antitone isomorphism of posets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does imply it. That terminology may be different than what I studied, though.

A finite Galois extension $k\rightarrow L$ gives $L$ the structure of a finite $k$-algebra. The separable condition implies it is an étale algebra. As a $k$-algebra, $L$ has finite spectrum (the points are to be seen as roots of polynomials with coefficients in $k$), and is a finite $G$-set, with $G$ being the Galois group.

Here, the equivalence maps subextensions (which are morphisms in the category of $k$-algebras) into quotients of those $G$-sets (which are the spectrums, aka, the roots of the polynomial one gets by extending the field, which are permuted by the corresponding Galois groups).

Sorry, it's a messy explanation, since it's been a long time I studied this. I only know of this source: [http://matematicas.unex.es/~navarro/acb.pdf](http://matematicas.unex.es/%7Enavarro/acb.pdf)

It's Juan Antonio Navarro's book on Commutative Algebra. Galois Theory is developed throughout the appendices on Finite algebras, Separable algebras, Galois theory, etc.

Comment: I don't really understand your argument. What is it that makes you conclude an isomorphism of posets from an equivalence of categories?

Comment: Inclusions are the same as morphisms. I can't really give much more detail, it's been ages seen I read that, and only very superficially.